# Finding Product of Scattered Variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hi I came across the following question where I need to find $$mk$$ from $$ (x-2) (x+k) = x^2 + mx - 10 $$ The answer is 15. Any suggestions on how I could do that ?

Comment: Use the relation between the roots of a polynomial and its coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of the roots $(2, -k)$ equals  $-m$.  The product of the roots $-2k=-10$. Therefore $k=5$ and $m=3$.

Comment: Thanks for the great solution . I realize that 2,-k are the two roots. However I did not know that sum of the roots (2,−k) equals −m. and the product of the roots -10 can be obtained from the equation. Could you show me how you got that or link to any references please..

Comment: If you expand the left hand side, you get it.
$(x-a)(x-b)=x^2+px+q$
$x^2-(a+b)x+ab=x^2+px+q$
It's true for polynomials over any field.

Comment: Aneesh gave the full explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You can find the product $(x-2)(x+k)$, getting $x^2+(k-2)x-2k$.  This is supposed to be the same polynomial as $x^2+mx-10$.

So the constant terms must match, and the coefficients of $x$ must match. That gives us $-2k=-10$ amd $k-2=m$.  From $-2k=10$, we conclude that $k=5$. Then from $k-2=m$ we conclude that $m=3$. It follows that $mk=15$.

Answer (score 1):

Expression$$ (x-2) (x+k) = x^2 + mx - 10 $$ 
can be rewriten as
$$ x^2+(k-2)x-2k = x^2 + mx - 10 $$
equating the coefficients next to same power of $x$
we get that
$k-2=m$ and $-2k=-10$ or$ k=5$ and $m=5-2=3$ that means $$mk=5\times 3=15$$

Comment: Your second equation (k-2) is missing an x

Comment: there is $x^0=1$